# Python import syntax

Tags: python, syntax, import

Does this:

```
import foo as bar
```

do the same thing as this?

```
bar = __import__('foo')
```

Is there ever a reason to use the latter one?

I'm reading through someone elses code, I found the latter one and am not sure why they didn't use the prior syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Direct use of `__import__()` is rare, except in cases where you want to import a module whose name is only known at runtime.

[source](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)

Answer (score 6):

The two statements do the same thing.   The only reason to use the latter syntax is not knowing the module name in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) by Fredrik Lundh:

> Python provides at least three
>   different ways to import modules. You
>   can use the `import` statement, the
>   `from` statement, or the builtin
>   `__import__` function. (There are more
>   contrived ways to do this too, but
>   that’s outside the scope for this
>   small note.)

...

> X = `__import__`('X') works like
>   `import X`, with the difference that
>   you 
>  1) pass the module name as
>   a string, and 
>  2) explicitly
>   assign it to a variable in your
>   current namespace.

Comment: -1 for verbatim copying of a site with a copyright notice; SO contributions must be CC-wiki licensed

Comment: From the copyright notice "All text on this site is copyrighted, and cannot be republished or otherwise used without explicit permission by the author."  Fredrik Lundh won't sue you, but you should be aware of such issues.

Comment: i'll contact him to ask his permission

Comment: Edited to make attribution clear.  Small snippets may be fair use.  On the other hand, Serg makes no effort to provide context or explanation, or *any* of his own words.

Comment: @Steven: sure, it's probably legal, but that doesn't make it right.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the two forms are semantically the same. The later (`__import__('foo')`) is used when the module name is not known until runtime. The most common example of this is modules named in a configuration file or a plugin loading system. Django's configuration files, for example define plugin modules as strings (e.g. `some_plugin = 'foo.plugin'`) in a python configuration file, and Django loads these modules using `__import__`.